# При подключении сервопривода к arduino функции кода перестают работать. Что делать?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

У нас в программе есть несколько функций. Одной из них должно быть сжатие захвата манипулятора с помощью Сервопривода(Модель:Towerpro mg996R). Но, к сожалению, при подключении его в программе перестают работать другие функции. Питание осуществляется от батарей(Мощностью 12 Вольт). Используется плата Arduino UNO.
Буду благодарен за скорейший ответ, т.к. решаем сейчас, что делать дальше, а сроки поджимают.
Пример кода:

```
#define DRIVE_D0 3 //DRIVE_D0
#define DRIVE_D1 5 //DRIVE_D1
#define DRIVE_D2 6 //DRIVE_D2
#define DRIVE_D3 9 //DRIVE_D3
#define button_UP 4
#define button_LEFT 12
#include <Servo.h>

Servo s1;
int speed_motor = 80;
String a;
// variables will change:
int button_State_UP = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int button_State_LEFT = 0;


void full_stop_motors()
{
  // Задаём направление
  digitalWrite (DRIVE_D0, 0);
  digitalWrite (DRIVE_D1, 0);
  digitalWrite (DRIVE_D2, 0);
  digitalWrite (DRIVE_D3, 0);
}
void press_servo()
{
  s1.write(60);
}
void let_off_servo()
{
  s1.write(0);
}
void up()
{
  // Задаём направлениеd
  while (button_State_UP != 1) {
    button_State_UP = digitalRead(button_UP);
    analogWrite (DRIVE_D0, 0);
    analogWrite (DRIVE_D1, speed_motor);
  }
  full_stop_motors();
}

void down()
{
  // Задаём направление
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D0, speed_motor);
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D1, 0);
  delay(15000);
  full_stop_motors();
}
void ydown()
{
  // Задаём направление
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D0, speed_motor);
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D1, 0);
  delay(15000);
  full_stop_motors();
}

void turn_left()
{
  while (button_State_LEFT != 1) {
    button_State_LEFT = digitalRead(button_LEFT);
    analogWrite (DRIVE_D2, 0);
    analogWrite (DRIVE_D3, speed_motor);
  }
  full_stop_motors();
}
void turn_right_c()
{
  // Задаём направление
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D2, speed_motor);
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D3, 0);
  delay(1300);
  full_stop_motors();
}

void turn_right()
{
  // Задаём направление
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D2, speed_motor);
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D3, 0);
  delay(1400);
  full_stop_motors();
}

void centre()
{
  turn_left();
  full_stop_motors();
  turn_right_c();
  full_stop_motors();
}
void setup()
{
  pinMode(button_UP, INPUT);
  pinMode(button_LEFT, INPUT);
  button_State_LEFT = digitalRead(button_LEFT);
  button_State_UP = digitalRead(button_UP);
  pinMode(DRIVE_D0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DRIVE_D1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DRIVE_D2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DRIVE_D3, OUTPUT);
  full_stop_motors();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  button_State_LEFT = digitalRead(button_LEFT);
  button_State_UP = digitalRead(button_UP);
  if (Serial.available()) {       //From RPi to Arduino
    char r = Serial.read();  //conveting the value of chars to integer
    if (r == 'r') {
      turn_right();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == 'l') {
      turn_left();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == 'y') {
      ydown();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == 'u') {
      up();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == 'd') {
      down();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == 's') {
      full_stop_motors();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == 'c') {
      centre();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == '*') {
      press_servo();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == '/') {
      let_off_servo();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
  }
}

Амир_rblnÿ, [20.05.21 19:35]
#define DRIVE_D0 3 //DRIVE_D0
#define DRIVE_D1 5 //DRIVE_D1
#define DRIVE_D2 6 //DRIVE_D2
#define DRIVE_D3 9 //DRIVE_D3
#define button_UP 4
#define button_LEFT 12
#include <Servo.h>

Servo s1;
int speed_motor = 80;
String a;
// variables will change:
int button_State_UP = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int button_State_LEFT = 0;


void full_stop_motors()
{
  // Задаём направление
  digitalWrite (DRIVE_D0, 0);
  digitalWrite (DRIVE_D1, 0);
  digitalWrite (DRIVE_D2, 0);
  digitalWrite (DRIVE_D3, 0);
}
void press_servo()
{
  s1.write(60);
}
void let_off_servo()
{
  s1.write(0);
}
void up()
{
  // Задаём направлениеd
  while (button_State_UP != 1) {
    button_State_UP = digitalRead(button_UP);
    analogWrite (DRIVE_D0, 0);
    analogWrite (DRIVE_D1, speed_motor);
  }
  full_stop_motors();
}

void down()
{
  // Задаём направление
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D0, speed_motor);
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D1, 0);
  delay(15000);
  full_stop_motors();
}
void ydown()
{
  // Задаём направление
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D0, speed_motor);
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D1, 0);
  delay(15000);
  full_stop_motors();
}

void turn_left()
{
  while (button_State_LEFT != 1) {
    button_State_LEFT = digitalRead(button_LEFT);
    analogWrite (DRIVE_D2, 0);
    analogWrite (DRIVE_D3, speed_motor);
  }
  full_stop_motors();
}
void turn_right_c()
{
  // Задаём направление
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D2, speed_motor);
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D3, 0);
  delay(1300);
  full_stop_motors();
}

void turn_right()
{
  // Задаём направление
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D2, speed_motor);
  analogWrite (DRIVE_D3, 0);
  delay(1400);
  full_stop_motors();
}

void centre()
{
  turn_left();
  full_stop_motors();
  turn_right_c();
  full_stop_motors();
}
void setup()
{
  pinMode(button_UP, INPUT);
  pinMode(button_LEFT, INPUT);
  button_State_LEFT = digitalRead(button_LEFT);
  button_State_UP = digitalRead(button_UP);
  pinMode(DRIVE_D0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DRIVE_D1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DRIVE_D2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DRIVE_D3, OUTPUT);
  full_stop_motors();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  button_State_LEFT = digitalRead(button_LEFT);
  button_State_UP = digitalRead(button_UP);
  if (Serial.available()) {       //From RPi to Arduino
    char r = Serial.read();  //conveting the value of chars to integer
    if (r == 'r') {
      turn_right();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == 'l') {
      turn_left();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == 'y') {
      ydown();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == 'u') {
      up();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == 'd') {
      down();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == 's') {
      full_stop_motors();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == 'c') {
      centre();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == '*') {
      press_servo();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
    else if (r == '/') {
      let_off_servo();
      Serial.println(r);
    }
  }
}
```